# Postgre / SQL queries with recursive

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, circular-dependency

I'm trying to create a certain SQL query. First of all, here's the ER diagram and my created tables:

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE Course (
    CNr INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    costs NUMERIC(7, 2) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE requires (
    pred INTEGER REFERENCES Course(CNr),
    succ INTEGER REFERENCES COURSE(CNr),
    PRIMARY KEY(pred, succ)
);
```

The tables with their values look like this:

```
|   Course    |  |   requires  |
|-------------|  |-------------|
| CNr | costs |  | pred | succ |
|-----|-------|  |------|------|
|  1  |  100  |  |  1   |  2   |
|  2  |  200  |  |  1   |  3   |
|  3  |  300  |  |  2   |  3   |
|  4  |  400  |  |  3   |  4   |
```

What I need is to return a course's CNr and the costs of itself plus the sum of all predecessor courses. With the given tables, it shoud look like this:

```
| CNr | total |
|-----|-------|
|  1  |  100  |
|  2  |  300  |
|  3  |  600  |
|  4  |  1000 |
```

I've left out circular entries since it doesn't really make sense in this case (can't really ever do a course if they go in a circular order), so I'm not sure if you'd have to look for that too.
This should be somehow doable with WITH RECURSIVE, but I'm honestly at a loss. Could someone at least point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select pred, succ
      from requires r
      union all
      select cte.pred, r.succ
      from cte join
           requires r
           on cte.succ = r.pred
     )
select c.cnr, coalesce(sum(cpred.costs), 0) + c.costs
from course c left join
     (select distinct * from cte) cte
     on c.cnr = cte.succ left join
     course cpred
     on cte.pred = cpred.cnr
group by c.cnr, c.costs;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/58252/1) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Thanks! Could someone, however, explain what happens in the 

    coalesce(sum(cpred.costs), 0) + c.costs

part? I think I'm missing out on something.

Comment: That is just adding the cost for the current course to the cost of the predecessors.  The sum of the predecessors is `NULL` if there are none.

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple query first to see what you get:

```
SELECT
    CNr
    , COALESCE(
    (
        SELECT SUM( costs )
        FROM Course cr
        WHERE CNr IN (
            SELECT pred 
            FROM requires r
            WHERE r.succ = c.CNr
        )
    )
    , 0 )::INTEGER + costs AS total
FROM Course c
```

Comment: Thanks, however, the results are:

    1 - NULL
    2 - 100
    3 - 300
    4 - 300

Comment: Also 4 should = 700 not 1000 in you example

Comment: 4 does require 3 (which is 600, in total) plus the 400 it needs itself, though.

Comment: I had just edited it and chaged cost in the coalesce to 0. Its there. Guaranteed last time you'll have to try. Re-copy the code above

Comment: Oooh you mean it uses the sum. Ok, i'll see if I can work that out